# In vbs equivalent to php vardump?

Tags: vbscript, var-dump

I want to be able to dump the contents (all variables and types) of my variable to something I can see it in. ie( msgbox )

Comment: Are you talking about WSH? You might use debugger, e. g. MS Script Editor. There are also some workarounds on VBS, but no native support of such function.